# No plotly graph in folium popup

Tags: python, plotly, popup, folium

I am trying to embed a plotly barchart in a folium popup.

This is how I proceed in Google Colab :

```
# basic map :
map = folium.Map( location = [ 47.9060278 , 1.9020353 ] , zoom_start = 6, tiles = 'OpenStreetMap' )

# html file of plotly barchart :

fig = px.bar( a003_pdv_ca_his , x = 'mm' , y = 'ca' )

file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Data/a003_pdv_ca_his_20001.html'

fig.write_html( file_path )

with open( file_path , encoding = 'utf-8' ) as f :
  html = f.read()

# html in iframe :
iframe = branca.element.IFrame( html = html , width = 500 , height = 300 )

# folium popup from iframe :
popup = folium.Popup( iframe , max_width = 500 )

# add marker to the map :
folium.Marker( location = [ row.lat , row.lon ] , popup = popup , icon = folium.Icon( color = row.ins_clr ) ).add_to( map )

map
```

Infortunately the popup is empty. I see the barchart when opening the html file.

Has anyone an idea to fix this ? It might be of problem concerning the iframe...

Thanks for your help on that topic.

Comment: I think it is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76310297/plotly-chart-as-a-popup-in-folium-map), but I could not display the graph even if I run it in Colab at the moment. I also ran it with the version as of May of this year and could not display the graph. folium:0.14.0, plotly:0.14.0, branca:0.6.0, ipyleaflet:0.17.4 were used. Other changes than this may have affected the content.

Comment: I got inspired by the question you mentioned.

Comment: The problem seems to be at that level : iframe = branca.element.IFrame( html = html , width = 500 , height = 300 ). When I put the string '<html>toto/</html>' in html, the popup displays 'toto'.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite what I wanted but it could help some :

```
# base map :

map = folium.Map( location = [ 47.9060278 , 1.9020353 ] , zoom_start = 6, tiles = 'OpenStreetMap' )

# chart

chart = altair.Chart( a003_pdv_ca_his[ a003_pdv_ca_his[ 'id_pdv' ] == row.id_pdv ] ).mark_bar().encode( x = 'mm' , y = 'ca' )

data = json.loads( chart.to_json() )

# popup

popup = folium.Popup( max_width = "100%" )

# chart in popup

folium.features.VegaLite( data , width = 300 , height = 250 ).add_to( popup )

# marker, popup & graph 

folium.Marker( location = [ row.lat , row.lon ] , popup = popup , icon = folium.Icon( color = row.ins_clr ) ).add_to( map )
```

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding with my investigation, I tried this :

```
map = folium.Map( location = [ 47.9060278 , 1.9020353 ] , zoom_start = 6, tiles = 'OpenStreetMap' )

chart = altair.Chart( a003_pdv_ca_his[ a003_pdv_ca_his[ 'id_pdv' ] == 20001 ] ).mark_bar().encode( x = 'mm' , y = 'ca')

file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Data/chart.html'

chart.save( file_path )

with open( file_path ) as f :

   html = f.read()

iframe = branca.element.IFrame( html , width = 500 , height = 300 )

popup = folium.Popup( iframe , parse_html = True , max_width = 500 )

folium.Marker( location = [ 47.8928289 , 2.0214825 ] , popup = popup , icon = folium.Icon( color = 'green' ) ).add_to( map )

map
```

As it worked, I could conclude that the html file given by write_html of the plotly express figure was the weak spot.